# Rails mailboxer gem, send message to user using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mailboxer

I have installed the mailboxer gem to my rails app. It's successfully working when i'm using it in the console.
Exemple: `current_user.send_message(User.last, "Body", "subject")`

But i want to know how to do to make it work with a form view and a controller.
I want to be able to pass the send_message arguments through a view and send it to a message or a conversation controller.

I don't know the right way to handle this fantastic gem.
Thanks in advance

J.D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controller to send a message from a form:

```
class MessageController
  # GET /message/new
  def new
    # display form
  end

  # POST /message/create
  def create
    recipient = User.find(params[:recipient_id])
    current_user.send_message(recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
  end
end
```

Form view:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "messages", action: "create"}, method: :post) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :subject %>
  <%= text_area_tag :body %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Send email' %>
<% end %>
```

A field for the recipient is missing in this example.

Comment: Thank you zwippie but how will the form view look like ?

Comment: I added an example for the form view.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the basic knowledge in Actionmailer in rails take a look at the actionmailer

link:

```
guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html
```